# Laravel 5.6 return request data if validation fails issue

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

I want to return back request data into fields if validation fails on create action.
I've created resource controller and there is pre-set functions (index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy).

In example, in the **Edit** controller I already have an ID of a record, then I can just select record from DB by it's ID and pass it's data to the view, so that I will able to see entry data in fields on page load:

```php
<input name="name" value="{{ $name }}" />

public function edit($id)
{
   $item = Item::find($id);
   return view('pages.item.edit')->with($data);
}
```

But in the **Create** controller I do not have any ID of item to fetch and pass entry data for fields.

```php
<input name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" />

public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required|string|max:30'
   ])->withInput();
   return redirect('/items')->with('success', 'New item created!');
}
```

Should I use `->withInput()` and where? `{{ old('name') }}` doesn't work too.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214493/5246900) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23277027/5246900) articles didn't help me

So, how to save fields if validation fails? For **Edit** method it will be also useful to save modified fields.

Comment: you can do it the hard way with `$request->flash();` then retrieve it later after validation

Comment: @Hussein, thanks, is there any example for this approach?

Comment: You are doing something wrong, flashing to the session works by default, show us kernel.php and route you are using.

Comment: @Kyslik, I've just made a resource controller with artisan with pre-set functions. Does `flashing` work out of the box or should I import or add something? Is the any reliable example/guide for this? Still can't find described working solution for such simple task..

Comment: I personally never validate inside controller I just use [FormRequests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation), its really good practise.

Comment: try this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: you can retreive the flashed input with `session('field_name')`

Comment: I'am so sorry, guys... `{{ old('name') }}` works out of the box. I had some little mistake in my template. All in all, thanks a lot for pointing new approaches!